# how to find peak positions (local maxima)

Tags: dm-script

For the local maxima, could we set up some rule for the offset to make the curve only keep the plots we think they are peaks?

```
image FilterLocalMaxima1D( image spectrumIn, number range )
{
    image spectrumOut := spectrumIn.ImageClone()
    
    for( number dx = -range; dx<=range; dx++  )
    
        spectrumout *= ( spectrumIn >= offset(spectrumIn,dx,0)?1:0)
        
    spectrumout.SetName("Local maxima ("+range+") filtered")
    
    return spectrumOut
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't post multiple, separate questions in one post - rather post them separately.

#### As for your #1

You can simply make any image positive by taking its absolute values everywhere:

`img = abs(img)`

#### As for your #2

No, `offset` will always operate on the full image expression.

#### As for your #3

You can certainly print results into a separate text window instead of the results window. See F1 help documentation here:

```c
documentwindow win  = NewScriptWindow("My Text", 100, 100, 600, 900 )
win.EditorWindowAddText( "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\n" )
```

You can also save those text windows per script.
As for Excel: There is no direct functionality for that, but you might be able to do something creative with the `LaunchExternalProcess()` command.

Also, you can use the command `ScrapCopy()` as equivalent to pressing CTRL + C on an image, and then just paste that into Excel.  (Copy & Paste of lineplot data will give you the calibrated XY table. At least for recent GMS versions.)

Comment: Sure, will repost them separately, thank you

Comment: @together I think it's fine for now - but for future questions it's better to keep them separated.